# How to check member existing in list of tuples when member is unknown fully?

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml, exists

I have list of tuples and I want to check member existence in.
I can do this with `List.mem.` But in my case I know only one element of checking tuple and `List.mem` doesn't work.

For example:

```
let lst = [("x", 3); ("y", 4); ("z", 5)]
```

and following check is correct:

```
List.mem ("x", 3) lst
```

But I don't know the integer value only know string value. And try:

```
List.mem ("x", _) lst
```

and it doesn't work.

Is it possible to check ? How?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is to use `List.exists`.

Your particular type of list is called an "association list." So you might be interested in looking at `List.mem_assoc`.